# JS Sending parameters from a decorator to another

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-next, react-dnd

I have a component named DraggableAsset which is decorated by DragSource:

```js
@DragSource('DRAGGABLE_ASSET', spec, (connect, monitor) => ({
  connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
  isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
}))
export default class DraggableAsset extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    asset: PropTypes.instanceOf(AssetModel).isRequired,
    connectDragSource: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    isDragging: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  };

  render() {
    const {isDragging, connectDragSource, asset} = this.props;
    return connectDragSource(
      <div style={{opacity: isDragging ? 0.5 : 1}}>
        <img width={200} src={asset.get('url')} />
        <p>{asset.get('name')}</p>
      </div>,
    );
  }
}
```

I want to parameterize `'DRAGGABLE_ASSET'` string. Can i achieve that with another decorator like below?

```js
export function DraggableAssetDecorator(target, name, descriptor) {
  Object.defineProperty(target, 'TYPE', {value: 'DRAGGABLE_VIDEO'});
  return target;
}
```

Comment: How do you want to use those decorators? I guess it's possible, but I don't see how it has any advantage over explicitly passing the parameter to the decorator that uses it.

Comment: I want to use the component like `<DraggableAsset asset={myAssetObj} />` or a higher order component that wraps this component and use value of`myAssetObj.get('type')` as DragSource type.

Comment: You mean you would like to get the string dynamically from the constructor, not from another decorator?

Comment: Yes if possible, if not i thought i can use a decorator and a higher order component to do that.